# How do I invoke Python code from Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby

Does a easy to use Ruby to Python bridge exist?  Or am I better off using system()?

Comment: I asked a similar question here earlier; perhaps the answers would be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413878/would-it-be-possible-to-integrate-python-or-perl-with-ruby .

Answer (score 6):

You could try [Masaki Fukushima's library](http://www.goto.info.waseda.ac.jp/~fukusima/ruby/python-e.html) for embedding python in ruby, although it doesn't appear to be maintained. YMMV

> With this library, Ruby scripts can directly call arbitrary Python modules. Both extension modules and modules written in Python can be used.

The amusingly named [Unholy](http://github.com/why/unholy/tree/master) from the ingenious Why the Lucky Stiff might also be of use:

> Compile Ruby to Python bytecode.
>   And, in addition, translate that
>   bytecode back to Python source code
>   using Decompyle (included.)
>
> Requires Ruby 1.9 and Python 2.5.

Comment: Nice. Hadn't heard of unholy before.

Answer (score 6):

gem install rubypython

[rubypython home page](http://rubypython.rubyforge.org/)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any way to invoke Python from Ruby without forking a process, via system() or something.  The language run times are utterly diferent, they'd need to be in separate processes anyway.

Comment: invoke processes via the subprocess module. system() lacks a lot, let's kill the beast.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Python code like your Python script is a function, try IO.popen .

If you wanted to reverse each string in an array using the python script "reverse.py", your ruby code would be as follows.

```
strings = ["hello", "my", "name", "is", "jimmy"]
#IO.popen: 1st arg is exactly what you would type into the command line to execute your python script.
#(You can do this for non-python scripts as well.)
pythonPortal = IO.popen("python reverse.py", "w+")
pythonPortal.puts strings #anything you puts will be available to your python script from stdin
pythonPortal.close_write

reversed = []
temp = pythonPortal.gets #everything your python script writes to stdout (usually using 'print') will be available using gets
while temp!= nil
    reversed<<temp
    temp = pythonPortal.gets
end 

puts reversed
```

Then your python script would look something like this

```
import sys

def reverse(str):
    return str[::-1]

temp = sys.stdin.readlines() #Everything your ruby programs "puts" is available to python through stdin
for item in temp:
    print reverse(item[:-1]) #Everything your python script "prints" to stdout is available to the ruby script through .gets
    #[:-1] to not include the newline at the end, puts "hello" passes "hello\n" to the python script
```

Output:
olleh
ym
eman
si
ymmij

Comment: The author is looking to invoke python code from ruby, not ruby code from python.

Answer (score -1):

For python code to run the interpreter needs to be launched as a process. So system() is your best option.

For calling the python code you could use RPC or network sockets, got for the simplest thing which could possibly work.

Comment: Great, that's what I intend on doing.  Don't see any reason to be fancier than using system() alone.

Comment: I don't think that's true at all: see http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html for documentation of embedding the Python interpreter into another application. Which, for the perverse, could be the Ruby interpreter.