# Python and Ruby interpreter

Tags: python, ruby

I read in books that you are capable of incorporating scripts of other languages into Python. Is it possible to take variables from a ruby script, pass them to a python function, and then return the output back to Ruby? If so, how? Every answer will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look into http://rubypython.rubyforge.org

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few ways you *could* do it. Note that none of these has exceptionally high performance:

- It might be overkill, but I have used socket programming before to [set up a client-server relationship between Python and Ruby](http://michaeljgilliland.blogspot.com/2013/03/communication-between-python-and-ruby.html). At the very least this approach *feels* cool.
- You could write and read from a common file. But then you have to worry about [concurrency issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writers_problem).
- [backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338908/ruby-difference-between-exec-system-and-x-or-backticks) can be used to send something to a Python module. In the Python module you wouold then use `argv` to process the sent data and then return back some result to the Ruby code.

For further information I would suggest looking at [another similar StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837256/how-do-i-invoke-python-code-from-ruby).